# props.children in react cannot be a stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to practice render props patter in react but I got error of

> this.props.children is not a function

this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


const Box = ({color}) => (
  <div>
    this is box, with color of {color}
  </div>
);

class ColoredBox extends React.Component {
  state = { color: 'red' }
  getState() {
    return {
      color: this.state.color
    }
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.getState())
  }
}

render(<ColoredBox><Box /></ColoredBox>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/8z0xmk9ojl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the render props pattern, you need to have your children as a function, so you would indeed write

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


const Box = ({color}) => (
  <div>
    this is box, with color of {color}
  </div>
);

class ColoredBox extends React.Component {
  state = { color: 'red' }
  getState() {
    return {
      color: this.state.color
    }
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.getState())
  }
}

render(<ColoredBox>{(color) => <Box color={color}/>}</ColoredBox>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Also to make it clear, a stateless functional component is not treated the same as a function when you render it like `<Box/>`

However you could use the above stateless functional component like

```
<ColoredBox>{Box}</ColoredBox>
```

and it would work

**[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/w22wlorxvk)**

Comment: oops exactly how can I missed that

Comment: @MadelineRies, anyone can miss it, :-)

Answer (score 4):

As error says this.props.children is not a function or React Class(which is a function), instead it is an object created by invoking that function.

You can use this to fix the problem

```
render() {
 return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.getState())
}
```

This will take the child, clone it using extra props.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a React Object as props:

```
(<ColoredBox><Box /></ColoredBox>)
```

Therefore it is not a function.

use:

```
render() {
    return this.props.children
}
```

OR, if you want you can pass a function as children prop (render-props):

```
<ColoredBox>
  {state => <Box />}
</ColoredBox>

render() {
  return this.props.children(this.state)
}
```