# Receiving props.children is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

When attempting to pass custom props from layout to children, I am receiving the following: `TypeError: props.children is not a function`

**Layout** (functional component summary)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

export default (props) => {
    const {site} = useStaticQuery(
        graphql`
            {
                site {
                    siteMetadata {
                        title
                    }
                }
            }
        `
    )
    const globals = {title: site.siteMetadata.title}

    return (
        <>
            {props.children({...props, ...globals})}
        </>
    )
}
```

**Child** (also a functional component)

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <main>
                <h1>*site title will go here</h1>
            </main>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried console logging your props?

Comment: @AtinSingh Yes. I only receive the error when calling as a function to include custom "globals" props.

Comment: Can you show where you use Layout component?

Comment: Can you share the code of parent component? Is it a class or functional component?

Comment: Child component added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891935/props-children-in-react-cannot-be-a-stateless-component

Comment: I was viewing this post initially, to no avail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725557/pass-props-from-layout-to-children-in-gatsby

Comment: I think you should populate the children like this `Children.toArray(props.children)` instead of calling the props.children(), then pass the props using that

Comment: This guy somehow uses children as a function. I can't figure it out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54534202/916008

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Render function Pattern**

To use render function pattern you need to modified your child component as

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            {props => (<main>
                <h1>{props.title}</h1>
            </main>)}
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I really need to educate myself on this format.